Are Header always set X-Frame-Options "SAMEORIGIN" and Header set Content-Security-Policy: "frame-ancestors 'none'" duplicates or are both useful?
Sorry to trouble and please forgive if duplicate but I have looked!
I am trying to assemble security headers for htaccess to help my customers pass PCI Compliance.
I am not at all sure whether...
Header always set X-Frame-Options "SAMEORIGIN"
Header set Content-Security-Policy: "frame-ancestors 'none'"
...are essentially duplicates or whether they each have a role to play?
Advice gratefully received - thank you!

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/X-Frame-Options: "Warning: The Content-Security-Policy HTTP header has a frame-ancestors directive which obsoletes this header for supporting browsers." - CSP will do the job in all current, supporting browsers. Adding X-Frame-Options as well, to have older browsers covered, should not hurt. (CSP value none is not the same as X-Frame-Options SAMEORIGIN though.)
